# Possible to script a custom node for Compositor for: Look, Exposure?

Tags: python, compositing-nodes

I use look exposure gamma a lot during rendering and modeling.

But I would love to be able to have those tools as options inside the compositor so when you render
you do it straight raw and later can color correct it.

[image]

[image]